# Regex to match base name of files with multiple extensions

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match files of the following structure in PHP.

Input:

```
filename.ext1
filename.ext1.ext2
filename.ext3.ext2.ext1
filename.ext4.ext2.ext1.ext4
file name with spaces and no way of knowing how long.ext1
file name with spaces and no way of knowing how long.ext1.ext2
file name with spaces and no way of knowing how long.ext2.ext1.ext3
file name with spaces and no way of knowing how long.ext3.ext1.ext4.ext3
```

Output:

```
filename
filename
filename
filename
file name with spaces and no way of knowing how long
file name with spaces and no way of knowing how long
file name with spaces and no way of knowing how long
file name with spaces and no way of knowing how long
```

What I've already attempted (doesn't work of course and I already understand why):

```
^(?P<basename>.*)(\.ext4)|(\.ext3)|(\.ext2)|(\.ext1).*$
```

I'd like to extract the base name of the file and basically strip all extensions, because there's no way of knowing in which order they may appear. I've tried several solutions presented here but they did not work for me. The extensions could be anything alphanumeric of any length.

I'm fairly new to regular expressions and am confused that apparently you cannot simply search forward to the first dot and remove it including everything that comes after.

To learn, I'd also love to see how to do the reverse and just match all the extensions including the first dot.

**Update:**

I didn't think about file names that contain dots. So obviously my thinking regarding "searching forward" is flawed. Does anyone have a solution for the case

```
file name with spaces and no. way of knowing how long.ext3.ext1.ext4.ext3
```

or even

```
file name with spaces and no way of knowing.how.long.ext3.ext1.ext4.ext3
```

The latter one would quite possibly only work when certain extensions are given. So please assume ext1-4 are given but are in an unpredictable sequence.

Comment: Try something like `(\.ext\d)+`

Comment: do you have a fixed number of extensions or do you want anything before the first dot?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this will not work. I stated above: "The extensions could be anything alphanumeric of any length."

Comment: @kali: Yes, I'd like to get anything before the first extension.

Comment: In your very last example, how do we know that .how and .long are not also extensions?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
preg_replace("/\.(ext1|ext2|ext3|ext4)/i", "", $filename)
```

Comment: What if there are dots in the filename?

Comment: good point, I'm seeing that there are fixed extension, updating

Comment: Thanks. While this *would* work in pure PHP (I stated that in my question), I'm searching for a broader application. I'm using an app written in PHP (not my own) that filters and groups filenames by a given from a database. So unfortunately I cannot make any modifications to that. Therefore I'm searching for a regex to do that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use regular expressions for this; PHP has the buildin function [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) for that

Comment: Good point, but please see my previous comment why this would not work for me in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Does something simple like this works for you....

```
^[^.]*
```

Basically it just matches string before first dot.

Comment: What if there are dots in the filename?

Comment: Can you have dots in filename?

Comment: Thanks! That works great. And yes, I didn't think about filenames that contain dots. For these, your solution would not work.

Comment: @kingkero: It could happen, yes. Any solution for that?

Comment: @Srb1313711: It could happen, yes. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

> am confused that apparently you cannot simply search forward to the first dot and remove it including everything that comes after.

Since regexes are read from left to right, looking for a single dot will lead you straight to the first dot. That said, you would thus be able to use:

```
preg_replace("/\..*/", "", $filename);
```

`.*` matches any characters except newlines.

If the filename has dots, this obviously won't work, since part of the filename will then be removed.

---

As per update, if you have the specific extensions, you can use something like this:

```
preg_replace("/(?:\.ext[1-4])+$/m", "", $filename);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/nQ4oW8)

In a broader perspective, you could use something like this if you have an array of extensions at your disposition:

```
$exts = array(".ext1", ".ext2", ".ext3", ".ext4");
$result = preg_replace("/(?:". preg_quote(join("|",$exts)) .")+$/m", "", $filename);
```

Comment: @bubblun Updated my answer, if that is of any help at all.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you:

```
^.+?(?=\.[^.]*$)
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/uT2oK5

This will find file names before very last dot only. See all the examples included in the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
.*(?=\.)
```

Try this? Will match all before the last dot even if theres a dot in the file name

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with just plain old php functions. No need for fancy regex.

```
$name = substr($filename, 0, strpos($filename, '.'));
```

This won't work for filenames which have a . like your updated example, however in order to achieve this you would likely need to know in advance the extensions which you are likely to encounter.